# Get an image size and set a div size accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a `dijit dialog` and I need to set the dialog size according to the size of an image.

To achieve that I need to load the image before creating Dialog and get the properties from the image. Image `onload()` method is not fulfilling my requirement, because I need the size before creating the dialog and placing the image on it. Can anybody show me a way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: you could use body.onload()

Comment: Show what you have tried. If you need the size before creating the dialog then create it in your image onload, not before

Comment: You can load the image (`var i = new Image(); i.src = "url";`), wait until it has loaded, then create the dialog, then add the image to it. It's cached so it will appear right away.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am using dojo framework. I have two templated .js files: let's say- SmallThumbnail.js and LargeThumbnail.js. And I have one main .js file from where one of those two is called onclick(). Based on the size of an image a dijit.Dialog is created and height/width is set. Setting "height: auto" is not working on the dialog. That's why I need the size of the image before loading. Can't we internally load an image (without placing on dom) to get the properties?

Answer (score 0):

> Image onload() method is not fulfilling my requirement, because I need
>   the size before creating the dialog and placing the image on it.

Three steps:

1. Give the image a default of `display: none` in the stylesheet so that it does not display (or take up any space) when it loads.
2. Have javascript detect when the image loads and then run the function to set the dialog size.
3. Use javascript to replace `display:none` with `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get image properties before instantiating your dialog .

Note that the `dialog` dijit resize when the window is less larger than it's width ( so you can't force a fixed with )

Here is a snippet click -> Full page after runing the sample

```js
require(["dijit/Dialog","dijit/form/Button","dojo/domReady!"],function(Dialog,Button){
  
  var imageUrl = "https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/custom-trackable-short-url-feature.png";
  
  var dialog 
  var image = new Image();
  
  // passing src image url to call onload function without add to dom
  image.src = imageUrl;

  image.onload = function(e) {
   console.log(image.width);
    console.log(image.height);
    
    dialog = new Dialog({
      title: "My Dialog",
      /* if you want to pass the image */
      content: "<img src='"+imageUrl+"' />",
      style: "width:"+image.width+"px" 
    }); 
  }
  
  var btn = new Button({
        label: "Show me !",
        onClick: function(){
            dialog.show();
        }  
    }, "btn").startup();
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="btn"></div>
</body>
```